# send binary with sendDocument in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

this work :

```
mybot.sendDocument(chat_id=chatid, document=open('bla.pdf', rb'))
```

But if I did before :

```
with open('bla.pdf', 'rb') as fp:
    b = fp.read()
```

I can't do :

```
mybot.sendDocument(chat_id=chatid, document=b)
```

The error is :

> TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

I use python 3.5.2 win or linux

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

sorry I didn't see your answer.

My trouble was I wanted to send a downloaded document, not a document on disk.

I resolved it like this :

```
mybot.sendDocument(chat_id=chatid,document=io.BytesIO(self.downloaded_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send just a file object:

```
mybot.sendDocument(chat_id=chatid, document=open('bla.pdf', 'rb'))
```